# How can i send files asynchronously in a client-server application?(using winsock2.h, in C)

Tags: c, sockets, asynchronous, send

I want to send files asynchronously. I got on sending a file client->server->another client, but if i want to send a very big file, the client can't send any other commands to server until the file is totally sent. For every file client wants to send, i create a new thread in which i'll read 1kb of the file at a time and sending to the server, then the server will receive the 1kb and send further to the desired client. The problem is that when the client sends the file, the socket is full with bytes from server. I should make one client-server socket for every file i want to send? I've tried everything but nothing was a success.

Answer (score 1):

Creating dedicated sockets for each transfer is one solution, and it's not a bad one unless the number of simultaneous connections is large (only so many IP  ports are available on a system, and the server will need twice as many).  Threads don't simplify this as much as you might think, and introduce their own challenges; [`select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) is a simpler way to efficiently transfer data on multiple sockets from a single thread/process.  It works by exposing the underlying operating system's knowledge of which sockets are ready for reading and writing to the program.

The challenge for you with the multi-socket approach, regardless of threading choices, is that the server will have to tell the *recipient* to open a new connection back to the server for each new transfer. Now you need a command mechansim to tell the recipient to open a new connection for the next file.

Another option would be to open only one socket, but send multiple files simultaneously over the socket.  You might accomplish this by sending a data structure containing the next parts of each file instead of simply streaming the file directly.  For example, you might send a message that looks something like this (rendered in JSON for clarity, but it would be a valid transport format):

```
[ 
  { 
    "name": "file.txt", 
    "bytes": "some smallish chunk of content", 
    "eof": false
  },
  { 
    "name": "another.txt", 
    "bytes": "chunk of another.txt content", 
    "eof": true
  }
]
```

This example is of course naively simplistic, but hopefully it's enough to get the idea across: By structuring the messages you're sending, you can describe to which files, which chunks of bytes belong, and then send multiple chunks of multiple files at once.  Because of your client->server->client approach, this seems like the best path forward to me.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The message that i send looks like this:"type"(this way server knows what type of command client sent, "numberOfBytesSent"(to verify the number of bytes send by client for example), "lengthUsername"(every client logged in has a username), "username", "lengthFile" (the size of name of the file sent) and  "fileName".. the problem is that if i use same socket client-server for sending files and for sending commands, the socket is blocked with sending files.. I'll try creating a new client-server socket for every file sent.

Answer (score 0):

using a struct similar to:

```
struct transferPacket
{
    unsigned packetOfFile;  // = 0 when starting a new file
    unsigned fileNumber;    // incremented with each new file
    unsigned byteCount; 
    char     payload[ MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN ];
};
```

When packetOfFile == 0 then starting a new file and payload contains filename
Otherwise indicates which part of file is being transfered.

When byteCount = 0 then EOF for that fileNumber

The above only takes a single TCP socket

multiple files can be transferred at one time.
The receiver knows which file the packet belongs to and which position in the file the payload belongs at.

The sender sends that same number of bytes each time, except for the first packet of a file and the EOF packet or the last data packet of the file